# auto update of Jira tickets once build is done + VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, jira, azure-pipelines, jira-plugin

I am looking for some pluggin or script that automatically changes the ticket status to 'ready for qa' once a build is done. My deployment pipeline is set up in VSTS. Can someone help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the status of Jira issue by rest API, in this way:

First, execute `http://localhost:8100/rest/api/latest/issue/MTF -2/transitions?expand=transitions.fields` and know the id’s for transitions.

For Eg: transition id for “Stop Progress” is 31, for “Done” is 41.

Once that is known, use the following link by adding values pertaining to your environment:

```
curl -D- -u <USER>:<PASS> -X POST --data '{"transition":{"id":"<TRANSITION_ID>"}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" <JIRA_URL>:<JIRA_PORT>/rest/api/latest/issue/<JIRA_ISSUE>/transitions?expand=transitions.fields
```

So at the end of the VSTS build definition add a command line or PowerShell task and run the above curl command.

*Note: you need curl installed on the build machine.*